# Excel VBA - Call application function (left, right) by name

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to be able to call application functions such as left() and right() using a string variable.

The reason is that my current code works fine, but has multiple instances of left() and right() that may need to change every time I run it. I'd like to be able to only change it once ("globally") every time.

After googling, I tried **CallByName** and **Application.Run**. It seems that they only work with a custom class/macro. Is this true? Is there anything else I should look into? I don't need specific code, thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's the code so far? You're trying to use `LEFT()` in VBA?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by string variable.  Do you mean as the thing being passed to the function, Right("TheLastLetterIsR", "1") where the number 1 is a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a custom function where you pass if you want `Left` or `Right`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Debug.Print LeftRight("L", "StackOverflow", 5)
    Debug.Print LeftRight("R", "StackOverflow", 8)

End Sub

Function LeftRight(sWhich As String, sValue As String, iLength As Integer) As String

    Select Case sWhich

        Case "L": LeftRight = Left(sValue, iLength)
        Case "R": LeftRight = Right(sValue, iLength)
    
    End Select

End Function
```

You just use "L" or "R" as needed. Change it once and pass as `sWhich` each time.
You can even use a cell reference for this and update the cell before running code.

Results

> Stack
>
> Overflow

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing my own function, but seems like there's no way around it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way around this is to replace all your `Left` and `Right` calls with a generic function, e.g. instead of

```
x = Left("abc", 2)
```

say

```
x = LeftOrRight("abc", 2)
```

and then have a function

```
Function LeftOrRight(str As Variant, len As Long) As Variant
    'Uncomment this line for Left
    LeftOrRight = Left(str, len)
    'Uncomment this line for Right
    LeftOrRight = Right(str, len)
End Function
```

Then you can just change the one function as required.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I chose Scott Holtzman's solution because I could change it along with my other variables in the main module.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `SWITCH` to implement Scott's idea (no error handling if string length is invalid):

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print LeftRight("L", "StackOverflow", 5)
    Debug.Print LeftRight("R", "StackOverflow", 8)
End Sub

Function LeftRight(sWhich As String, sValue As String, iLength As Integer) As String
     LeftRight = Switch(sWhich = "L", Left$(sValue, iLength), sWhich = "R", Right$(sValue, iLength))
End Function
```